# What kind of application would benefit from being written in F# opposed to the more conventional languages?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, f#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is F# being used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625882/)
>   [What are the benefits of using C# vs F# or F# vs c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952318/)

I have recently studied C#, WPF, a little bit of WCF and now I have read that Visual Studio 2010 will also support F#.

My question is: what kind of application is likely to need F# instead of C# or Visual Basic?

Is F# necessary to build Windows applications, which can already be written using C# and WPF?

Comment: If we interpret this as "What are the use cases that F# is intended to handle well", then it's not subjective or argumentative.

Comment: Thank you for editing the title of my question. Now it is more clear.

Comment: @Maurizio. Hope you don't mind by I changed the title to something a bit less subjective. You stand a better chance of it not being closed this way.

Comment: "Is it necessary to build Windows applications, which are so excellent when written using C# and WPF?" - can't understand that sentence, could you rephrase it?

Comment: @wwosik I think that the new title of my question express what I mean with that sentence. I'm sorry, but my english is not very good.

Comment: I think this should be re-opened. with the re-woreded title I don't see how this is subjective or augmentative. He is asking what are the reasons for choosing F#, or if there are any kinds of applications that would be better suited to F#.

Comment: There are already questions that address that; many are linked from this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625882/

Comment: Thank you Simon. I read other really "subjective and argumentative" questions in this site, and I don't think that mine is worse than those.

Comment: Here is another one that has some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952318/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-c-vs-f-or-f-vs-c

Comment: @those people who closed my question: Why stackoverflow.com/questions/36756/f-what-are-you-using-it-for was not closed? Isn't it "subjective and argumentative"?

Comment: @Simon thank you for providing to me another post where I can read the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: Don't take it too personally Maurizio. essentially I don't think it matters any more. There are plenty of duplicates so the question is basically answered. I suspect it was closed as subjective at least partly because of the original title, which in fairness was a bit subjective. Had it not been closed for that reason though, it would have been closed as a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"what kind of application need F# instead of C# or Visual Basic?" - None. It's just another way of expressing the concepts, although quite more different from both C# and VB and they differ among themselves.

Comment: Ok, but are there use cases where F# is better than the existing languages?

Comment: F# brings you type safe, succinct, efficient and expressive functional programming language on the .NET platform. It is a simple and pragmatic language, and has particular strengths in data-oriented programming, parallel I/O programming, parallel CPU programming, scripting and algorithmic development. It lets you access a huge .NET library and tools base and comes with a strong set of Visual Studio development tools. F# combines the advantages of typed functional programming with a high-quality, well-supported modern runtime system.