# Which is the difference between .cs and .fs file in xamarin.Android application?

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to learn how to do a very simple application with Xamarin.Android. I am using VS2019 community.

To create the new project, I choose the template empty application (Android). IN the solution explorer I can see my main.xaml y a file that it is MainActivity.fs.

My doubt is in this case. I have watch a tutorial in which the person is using VS2017 community, He selects Blank App (Android). But in his cases he has a MainActivity.cs file instead of MainActivity.fs file. And in the code he has use a class instead.

So my doubt is which is the difference between .fs and .cs files and which are the advantages and disadvantages of each type.

Thanks.

Comment: *I choose the template empty application (Android)* ... and F# language

Comment: `.cs` is the suffix for C# file while `.fs` is the suffix for the F# file.

Comment: you chosed F# as language and it generated .fs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.cs` means it's a C# file.

`.fs` is an F# file.

You can find more info about these two languages in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952318/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-c-sharp-vs-f-or-f-vs-c) SO question.